# Was Laxman Kumara named after Lakshmana?

Tags: mahabharata, name, etymology

[Laxman Kumara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laxman_Kumara) was the only son<sup>1</sup> of Duryodhana and Bhanumati. He battled in the Mahabharata war and did perform many acts of bravery, like saving King Bahlika, killing Shikandi's son, etc. He was later killed by Abhimanyu (who was killed on the same day).

However, what interests me is the proximity of his name, "Laxman Kumara", to that of Lord Rama's brother, Lakshmana. Are there any mentions about him being named after Lakshmana, or about how they chose his name?

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>(they had another *daughter*, Lakshma, who was the wife of Samba, son of Lord Krishna)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mention of naming ceremony of Lakshmana Kumara, son of Duryodhana. So, we can't say that he was named after Lakshmana, son of Dasharatha.

BUT,

People were named in the past based on their qualities or physical attributes which is why we find many people having same names in the epics and Puranas. For example, Rama means the one on whom people take delight.

> Rama = ramante sarve janaaH guNaiH asmin iti raamaH
>
> 'in whom all the people take delight for his virtuousness, thus he is Rama

Since, people take joy in him  That is why Parashurama who was born before Sri Rama and Bala Rama who was born after Sri Rama were named.

Similarly, Lakshmana [is defined as](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga18/balasans18.htm#Verse21)

> *Lakṣmaṇo lakṣmī saṃpanno*
>
> enhancer of the property.

Vashishta named Lakshmana keeping the above meaning in mind along with few other ones.

So, it is possible that Lakshmana Kumara is named after the meaning of the name rather than Lakshmana, the brother of Rama.  It is possible that his sister is also named Lakṣmaṇā following the same principle.

Comment: "There is no mention of naming ceremony of Lakshmana Kumara" - On what basis you are claiming this..Have you studied all the scriptures? If not, Can you please mention the fact that it is not mentioned in scriptures A, B, C etc...

Comment: @YDS  Kind of. If you can find it somewhere in the scripture, then cite it. I will modify it or delete it.

Comment: @YDS It is a fact that the story of Lakshman kumara's naming is not mentioned in authentic scriptures. His stories are present in some folklores. If I start naming it is not present in A,B,C, it will not in z and I have to say ज्ञ  and start counting in other languages. It overshadows the main answer. The main answer is not in the first answer it is after BUT. It would be good if you see that one. Put aside Lakshmana kumar, is there a mention of same thing for Abhimanyu, who is more important character? Answer is no. It's a fact.

Comment: "Put aside Lakshmana kumar, is there a mention of same thing for Abhimanyu, who is more important character? Answer is no. It's a fact." -
 No it's not fact..For Abhimanyu it's mentioned.."Subhadra, the favourite sister of Kesava, gave birth to an illustrious son..... **was called Abhimanyu because he was fearless and wrathful** ....Upon the birth of this child, Yudhishthira, the powerful son of Kunti, gave away unto Brahmanas ten thousand cows and coins of gold..." due to character limit i have removed few words..pls see http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01224.htm for more details...

Answer (score 2):

In the book, [The Mahabharata: A Modern Rendering - By Ramesh Menon](https://books.google.com/books?id=uA-2_WMhpzoC&lpg=PA246&ots=ErFU_dISRJ&pg=PA247#v=onepage&q&f=false), which is a new abridged version of the Mahabharata, the author mentions that:

> Duryodhana’s beautiful son Lakshmana Kumara rides at Abhimanyu from a flank. A wild duel
>   breaks out between the cousins. Fire in his eye, Duryodhana roars encouragement at his boy; and for
>   a while, it seems Abhimanyu is contained. He cannot lacerate the Kaurava legions any more; Lakshmana absorbs him. **Duryodhana’s son fights like the prince of old, Rama’s brother, after whom he is
>   named.** But then, Abhimanyu pierces his throat with a perfect arrow. With his father watching in
>   horror, Lakshmana Kumara dies.

(emphasis mine)

Thus according to the interpretation of that author, Lakshmana Kumara was named after Rama's brother, Lakshmana.

However in the footnotes, he mentions that "He is as handsome as a yaksha prince, even a **son of Kubera**", which emphasizes the other answer from [Sarvabhouma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24029/4459), which mentions that he might have been named after his virtues.